# How to control order of relation query

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, schema, history

Is there some magic in Symfony/doctrine with a model called JosVmOrderHistory?

I have this schema.yml excerpt:

```
JosVmOrder:
  tableName: jos_vm_orders
  columns:
    order_id: { type: integer(4), primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    user_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
    vendor_id: { type: integer(4), notnull: true }
    order_number: { type: string(32), notnull: false }
    user_info_id: { type: string(32), notnull: false }
    order_total: { type: 'decimal(15, 5)', notnull: true }
    order_subtotal: { type: 'decimal(15, 5)', notnull: false }
    order_tax: { type: 'decimal(10, 2)', notnull: false }
    order_tax_details: { type: string(), notnull: true }
    order_shipping: { type: 'decimal(10, 2)', notnull: false }
    order_shipping_tax: { type: 'decimal(10, 2)', notnull: false }
    coupon_discount: { type: 'decimal(12, 2)', notnull: true }
    coupon_code: { type: string(32), notnull: false }
    order_discount: { type: 'decimal(12, 2)', notnull: true }
    order_currency: { type: string(16), notnull: false }
    order_status: { type: string(1), notnull: false }
    cdate: { type: integer(4), notnull: false }
    mdate: { type: integer(4), notnull: false }
    ship_method_id: { type: string(255), notnull: false }
    customer_note: { type: string(), notnull: true }
    ip_address: { type: string(15), notnull: true }
  relations:
    User: { class: JosUser, local: user_id, foreignAlias: OrderList }
    LatestVmOrderDetail: { class: LatestVmOrderDetail, local: order_id, foreign: order_id }

JosVmOrderHistory:
  tableName: jos_vm_order_history
  columns:
    order_status_history_id: { type: integer(4),primary: true, autoincrement: true }
    order_id: { type: integer(4) }
    order_status_code: { type: string(1) }
    date_added: { type: timestamp(25) }
    customer_notified: { type: integer(4), notnull: false }
    comments: { type: clob(16777777), notnull: false }
  relations:
    Order: { class: JosVmOrder, local: order_id, foreign: order_id }
    OrderStatus: { class: JosVmOrderStatus, local: order_status_code, foreign: order_status_code }
```

Firstly, the foreignAlias of JosVmOrderHistory is "JosVmOrderHistory", not "JosVmOrderHistoryList" as I would have assumed.

Secondly, in model/doctrine/Order.class.php, I have the following function:

```
function getPaymentStatus(){

    $historyList = $this->getJosVmOrderHistory();
    if (count($historyList)){

        return $paymentStatus = $historyList[0];
    }else{
        return $paymentStatus = null;
    }
}
```

$historyList is always in descending order of order_status_history_id. I even added to model/doctrine/JosVmOrderHistoryTable.class.php:

```
public function createQuery($alias){

    return parent::createQuery($alias)->orderBy('order_status_history_id asc');


}
```

but it stays in descending order..

Edit: I've updated the subject - this problem seems to come down to how to control the OrderBy of a relation query. createQuery doesn't seem to be called at all.

Comment: Have you considered just sorting the array rather than trying to change how Doctrine behaves? Otherwise, query for the related data directly instead of accessing it through a getter on the other object.

Comment: Thanks Dan, no hadn't considered that. I need this for speed reasons, basically the relation needs to be included in a table_method and custom sorting needs to work.
I have now build a MySQL View and created a relation for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need this for speed reasons you shouldnt load the entire order history from the DB if you are just interested in the first one, instead use a query like:

```
function getPaymentStatus(){

    $historyList = Doctrine::getTable('JosVmOrderHistory')->createQuery()->where('order_id = ?', $this->order_id)->orderBy('order_status_history_id')->limit(1)->execute();
    if (count($historyList)){

        return $paymentStatus = $historyList[0];
    }else{
        return $paymentStatus = null;
    }
}
```

That being said, it is possible to automatically affect the sorting more like what you were trying to do by using a listener. In the past, I have created a generic sort behavior that you can use like:

```
  actAs:
    DefaultSort: { column: title }
```

Comment: Thanks, I have come to the same conclusion. The speed issue is not here by calling getPaymentStatus(), but actually a table method, which would require a table subquery however (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6434310/doctrine-subquery-in-select-with-join).

In the end I used a MySQL View and joined it in the table_method.

That said, can you elaborate on where my Listener function would sit?

Comment: I implemented the listener as a behavior, but I think if you wanted it just for this one class, it would go into the class during setup. Like in the setTableDefinition() function add the listener using $this->addListener(). The listener itself needs to be its own class. If you are using solely for this class, then just put the definition for it in the same file. The listener class should extend Doctrine_Record_Listener and implement the preDqlSelect() function.

Comment: for the preDqlSelect function, you could use code something like:

Comment: $query = $event->getQuery();
      $orderby = $query->getDqlPart('orderby');

      // only apply the default sort if no other sort has been set
      if(count($orderby) == 0)
      {
         $query->orderBy("order_status_history_id");
      }